# Which uses less memory? Adding item to long list in Clojure atom or an item to a map?

Tags: clojure

I am working on something where I update an many items which are ordered in a Clojure atom. I can either store the items as a vector or as an indexed map. There may be millions of appendages to the items, so I want to choose the most memory efficient structure.

My gut feeling is that adding a new item to a map uses less memory than compared to a vector over millions of iterations, but would like to get a definitive answer:

So with a vector it could be:

```
["a" "b"  ... "y"] -> ["a" "b"  ... "y" "z"]
```

And with a map it would be:

```
{0 "a"    1 "b"  ... 25 "y"} -> {0 "a"   1 "b"  ... 25 "y"   26 "z"}
```

So which would use less memory?

Comment: Your question mentions the `list` datatype, which strictly speaking would use the least memory, but neither of your proposed solutions use it.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: I'm curious -- why the gut expectation that a map would be more efficient? Also, after GC has run and the atom's history (which isn't all that long to start with) has flushed, there's not necessarily that much difference between creating a million-item collection and appending to an empty collection a million times, so the way the question is posed is a bit odd.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. So does the history of atoms flush after some time?

Comment: I thought that a map would be more efficient because I thought that a vector would have to be fully traversed and maybe fully replaced every time a change was made whereas a map entry could just be looked up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Clojure both vectors and hash maps use [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) as their fundamental implementation technique.

Clojure's vectors use the index of the element directly as the value of the key to walk the trie in order to find the value. Bit partitioning is used in order to split the index into chunks of bits that can be used as the key at each level.

Clojure's hash maps, on the other hand, *hashes* the provided index to create a key to walk the trie in order to find the value. Bit partitioning is used on the hashed index rather than on the index directly.

The actual key used to traverse the trie for both vectors and hash maps will be a 32-bit int.

I would expect the difference in memory usage between vectors and hash maps to be negligible. The hash map should use slightly more memory in order to cater for key collisions and therefore having to have the overhead of hash buckets.

There is a more in-depth discussion on the implementation details of both vectors and hash maps [available here](http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/09/08/understanding-clojures-persistenthashmap-deftwice).